# Use previously calculated values in aggregate function when querying with Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'd like to be able to use previously calculated values in a Mongoose aggregation query, something like:

```
const aggregate = await Model.aggregate([
    {
      $group: {
        _id: { id: `$id` },
        timeStart: {
          $min: `$aTime`,
        },
        timeLatest: {
          $max: `$aTime`,
        },
        timeLength: {
          $subtract: [`$timeStart, $timeLatest`,],
        },
      },
    },
  ]);
```

This obviously doesn't work - What would be the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there's a separate individual operator for this case: `$addFields`

```
const aggregate = await Model.aggregate([

    {
      $group: {
        _id: { id: `$id` },
        timeStart: {
          $min: `$aTime`,
        },
        timeLatest: {
          $max: `$aTime`,
        },
      },
      {
        $addFields: {
          difference: { $subtract: [`$timeLatest`, `$timeStart`] },
      },
    },

    },
  ]);
```